What's the right way to get a Test Account for developing a Google Classroom Add-On?
My company already has an existing web application that is used by many instructors and institutions. It has been popularly requested that we offer Google Classroom integration via add-on (similar to how we have an LTI integration with Blackboard and Canvas).
I am following the developer guides, but it is not clear how I can test/develop my add-on. I just want to be certain about what my options are to correctly test a Google Classroom add-on during development.
I have created a Google Cloud Project and configured Oauth. From my understanding, I need to obtain a Google Workspace for Education account.
**What I tried:
**
I followed
https://developers.google.com/classroom/support/access#get_an_administrative_test_domain to get a Google Workspace for Education demo test domain -- our administrator applied for the Google Cloud Partner Advantage Program, but our solution qualification has not been approved. I think this might not be applicable to my use-case either. I thought it would get approved and I'd get a test account.
I see https://developers.google.com/classroom/support/access#get_a_developer_test_domain as well. I'm not sure if it necessary to purchase a ".demo" domain, because I was expecting a cost-free process. And it only provides a 2 week trial, what if our development takes more than that? It's not clear which process is correct, and I want to be sure of it before proceeding/paying.

You're exactly right that you'll need a Workspace for Education domain. Please follow the steps listed in Create a private Google Cloud project to request a demo domain. The form submitted in Step 3 is the critical one.
We're actually in the middle of restructuring this process and the Classroom API guides, so I understand that things are a bit confusing.
